# Visual Studio Code - переход в файл с методом по Ctrl+Click

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

кто работает на VSC ? Подскажите какой плагин нужен что бы перемещаться в файл с методом или классом по Ctrl+Click по нему как в PHPStorm ?

Comment: Плагин называеся *PhpSrorm*  :)))

Comment: PHP IntelliSense
v1.1.4

Comment: Кто пишет `PHP` на `VsCode`? перейдите на `PhpStorm`.

Comment: весь мир пишет на VSCode, и я нисколько не жалею что ушел с PHPStorm... Куча плагинов и все бесплатно!